# Printing out 2D array

Tags: arrays, pointers, parameter-passing

I'm trying to create a 2d array by passing a variable in parameter of the function. Can you please look at my code for any errors, thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void print(char *board)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    printf("Board :\n");
    for(i; i < 3 ;i++)
    {
        for(j; j < 3;j++)
        {
            board[i][j] = 'X';
            printf("%c", board[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}


int main()
{
    char board[3][3];
    print(&board[0][0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Seems fine.  Does it work?  You can simplify the call by writing print( board ) in the main.

Comment: It does not work. I can't find any reason why it won't work.

Comment: This question would be more suited to be posted at Code Review, as it stands it's not a good fit for Stackoverflow, without a description of the error you are experiencing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not initializing `j` in the inner loop so it is running for only `i=0`,
after that `j` becomes `3` as you are not initializing it in loop then condition `j < 3` will always be **false** for further values of `i` , so inner loop will never execute again.

And if you want to print new line after every row then your `printf("\n");` statement should be inside the first for loop(See the code).

Change your code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void print(char board[][3])
{
    int i,j;

    printf("Board :\n");
    for(i=0; i < 3 ;i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j < 3;j++) // initialize j to 0
        {
            board[i][j] = 'X';
            printf("%c", board[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n"); //new line after each row
    }

}


int main()
{
    char board[3][3];
    print(board);
    return 0;
}
```